# Is there a data set of elementary typical phrases translated in different languages?

Tags: cross-linguistic, corpora, syntax-trees

To be more explicit, I think about a collection of "abstract" sentences which could be categorized in such a way that they would be easily identified in any language. For example, some typical phrases classified in question/location/movement-from/present would be: *Where are you from?*; *D'où viens-tu ?*; *Woher kommst du ?* ; ... and others in assertion/time-period/past could be: *It was during the 1970s.*; *C'était dans les années 70.*; *Es war während der 1970er.* The result would be a set of elementary sentences that could be learn by language learners to memorize key words or usual phrase structures in a foreign language or that could be a tool for interested people to compare how different languages express the same idea.

PS: I am not a professional linguist or anything related to this, so I hope the vocabulary/examples I used is not somewhat confusing for you...

Comment: Are you wanting a "Swadesh list" for phrases instead of individual words?

Comment: I never read about the "Swadesh list" before but that's indeed similar to what I am looking for, but for phrases as you said. Another difference is that the size of the list should not be limited to one or two hundreds items... Actually I found this kind of thing in a bookstore, in a "phrases dictionary" for tens of languages, but it was a big, very limited and not very convenient book ^^